# How to do hibernate pagination in spring bean?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, pagination

I have spring dao bean called `HostelDaoImpl`. It uses hibernate criteria api to retrieve results.

```
public class HostelDaoImpl extends AbstractGenericDao<Hostel, Integer> implements HostelDao {

    public HostelDaoImpl() {
        super(Hostel.class);
    }

    public List<Hostel> findHostelBy(HostelSearch hs) {
            Criteria criteria = currenSession().createCriteria(Hostel.class);
            criteria.setReadOnly(true);

            Calendar beginDate = hs.getBeginDate();
            String country = hs.getCountry();

            if (beginDate != null)
                criteria.add(Restrictions.le("beginDate", beginDate));

            if (country != null) {
                criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("country", country));
            }

            criteria.setProjection(Projections.rowCount());
            Integer foundHostelsCount = (Integer) criteria.uniqueResult();

            if (foundHostelsCount > 100) {
                // do pagination
            }
    }
}
```

Now in place of those comments I need pagination.
I want to create `Criteria` only once and then store `Criteria` somewhere and call `Criteria`'s `setFirstResult` and `setMaxResults` each time when user requests new portion of data.

Where to store `Criteria` if spring bean `HostelDaoImpl` is singleton and if I create instance variable `Criteria criteria` it is concurrently unsafe.

Where to store Criteria so that it is thread safe?

But if you know better way to achieve hibernate pagination in spring bean please provide it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use CRUD repositories. It supports pagination

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the Jquery plugin JQGrid to show in a table the results, and it's very easyly to hibernate pagination.

http://jqgrid.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pageRequest` for pagination.
follow the steps on [this link](http://springinpractice.com/2012/05/11/pagination-and-sorting-with-spring-data-jpa).
This link is very helpful. The link explains everything till `JSP` page.